# How can I get if comsumer subscribed in flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, client-server, messaging

Recently I've found out that consumer in Flex 4 doesn't subscribe immediatelly after subscribe method invocation. I didn't find any opportunities to define if consumer is subscribed. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Subscribe to what ???

Comment: I have an application. Back end - Flex. Java (BlazeDS) - server side. When user logins, server starts sending messages. Flex appl subscribes before user logins, but sometimes it doesn't get first message. I found out that it is happening because consumer needs some time to subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. All I have to do is just listen to PropertyChangeEvent and check if subscribed and connected variables are true.